# BITAND SQL - Operation between hexadecimal data Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, function, hex

I need resolve the following situation:

I have the following twelve rows in a table A_5MIN_TST1 (the data to be compared are hexa, but examples works with decimal values):

```
UTCTIME|TLQ_INST
01/08/2013 01:05:00 a.m.|32
01/08/2013 01:10:00 a.m.|128
01/08/2013 01:15:00 a.m.|8
01/08/2013 01:20:00 a.m.|32
01/08/2013 01:25:00 a.m.|1
01/08/2013 01:30:00 a.m.|10
01/08/2013 01:35:00 a.m.|100
01/08/2013 01:40:00 a.m.|1000
01/08/2013 01:45:00 a.m.|2000
01/08/2013 01:50:00 a.m.|3000
01/08/2013 01:55:00 a.m.|4000
```

Doing a select I must analyze each bit of the tlq_inst column (hexadecimal data) and decide:

If some value of tlq_inst is
= 8
or
= 32
or
= 128
then write = 8.
When tlq_inst doesn't is 8, 32, 128 then write the first value of tlq_inst, over the range.

I have tried with this query:

```
SELECT DECODE(POWER(2,BITAND(tlq_inst, 168)), 1, 'OK','Q') salida
FROM A_5MIN_TST1
WHERE utctime >= TO_DATE ('01/08/2013 01:00:01','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
AND utctime < TO_DATE ('01/08/2013 02:00:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
AND POINTNUMBER = 330062;
```

And I received these results:

```
SALIDA
Q
Q
Q
Q
OK
Q
Q
Q
Q
Q
Q
Q
```

Resuming, on these 12 values, I need to do:

- Get 'Q' if the comparison condition with mask is met.
- Get the first value of tlq_inst, when the comparison with the mask, is NOT true.

If possible, do the same but inside where

With this query I managed to get 12 values, but I need to get only one.

Could you help me to resolve this problem?

```
CREATE TABLE A_5MIN_TST1
(
  UTCTIME      DATE                             NOT NULL,
  POINTNUMBER  INTEGER                          NOT NULL,
  SITEID       INTEGER,
  VALOR_INST   FLOAT(126),
  TLQ_INST     INTEGER,
  VALOR_PROM   FLOAT(126),
  TLQ_PROM     INTEGER,
  VALOR_MAX    FLOAT(126),
  TLQ_MAX      INTEGER,
  UTCTIME_MAX  DATE,
  VALOR_MIN    FLOAT(126),
  TLQ_MIN      INTEGER,
  UTCTIME_MIN  DATE
)
TABLESPACE USERS
PCTUSED    0
PCTFREE    10
INITRANS   1
MAXTRANS   255
STORAGE    (
            INITIAL          64K
            MINEXTENTS       1
            MAXEXTENTS       UNLIMITED
            PCTINCREASE      0
            BUFFER_POOL      DEFAULT
           )
LOGGING 
NOCOMPRESS 
NOCACHE
NOPARALLEL
MONITORING;


ALTER TABLE A_5MIN_TST1 ADD (
  PRIMARY KEY
 (UTCTIME, POINTNUMBER)
    USING INDEX 
    TABLESPACE USERS
    PCTFREE    10
    INITRANS   2
    MAXTRANS   255
    STORAGE    (
                INITIAL          64K
                MINEXTENTS       1
                MAXEXTENTS       UNLIMITED
                PCTINCREASE      0
               ));


SET DEFINE OFF;
Insert into A_5MIN_TST1
   (UTCTIME, TLQ_INST)
 Values
   (TO_DATE('08/01/2013 01:05:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 32);
Insert into A_5MIN_TST1
   (UTCTIME, TLQ_INST)
 Values
   (TO_DATE('08/01/2013 01:10:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 128);
Insert into A_5MIN_TST1
   (UTCTIME, TLQ_INST)
 Values
   (TO_DATE('08/01/2013 01:15:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 8);
Insert into A_5MIN_TST1
   (UTCTIME, TLQ_INST)
 Values
   (TO_DATE('08/01/2013 01:20:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 32);
Insert into A_5MIN_TST1
   (UTCTIME, TLQ_INST)
 Values
   (TO_DATE('08/01/2013 01:25:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 1);
Insert into A_5MIN_TST1
   (UTCTIME, TLQ_INST)
 Values
   (TO_DATE('08/01/2013 01:30:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 10);
Insert into A_5MIN_TST1
   (UTCTIME, TLQ_INST)
 Values
   (TO_DATE('08/01/2013 01:35:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 100);
Insert into A_5MIN_TST1
   (UTCTIME, TLQ_INST)
 Values
   (TO_DATE('08/01/2013 01:40:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 1000);
Insert into A_5MIN_TST1
   (UTCTIME, TLQ_INST)
 Values
   (TO_DATE('08/01/2013 01:45:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 2000);
Insert into A_5MIN_TST1
   (UTCTIME, TLQ_INST)
 Values
   (TO_DATE('08/01/2013 01:50:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 3000);
Insert into A_5MIN_TST1
   (UTCTIME, TLQ_INST)
 Values
   (TO_DATE('08/01/2013 01:55:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 4000);
COMMIT;
```

Comment: I don't understand. I see how you get the Qs and OKs (although testing wether 2^x = 1 is simply asking wether x = 0). But now you say you want to aggregate these twelve lines somehow? Please explain again.

Comment: I hope to be more clear:
If any of the 12 rows have "tlq_inst" that meets with the condition of the mask, then 'Q'

utctime  tlq_inst
1            8          --> 'Q'
2            32         --> 'Q'
3            1
.
.
12           3
there is 'Q', I write 'Q'

Otherwise, if none of the 12 rows has a value of "tlq_inst" that meets the condition of the mask, then 'OK'
utctime  tlq_inst
1            1
2            3
3            5
.
.
12           7

All 'OK', then, I must get the first value "tlq_inst=1" (ordered by "min (UTCTime)") of the 12 rows
Thanks

Comment: I still don't understand completely. You call a match Q and a non-match OK. You want one single result value. This is: When all records = Q then Q? When all records = OK then first value ordered by time? When some Q and some OK then OK? Is that what you want?

Comment: "When some Q and some OK then OK?"  then --->   Q   . Thanks for your interesting

Answer (score 0):

Here is a statement giving you Q when at least one record matches the bitmask and the earliest TLQ_INST otherwise. It uses KEEP DENSE_RANK. It orders the records by utctime, gets the earliest record and returns the tlq_inst of that record. In case there are more records with the same earliest time, it returns the maximum tlq_inst of these records.

```
select 
  case when max(bitand(tlq_inst, 168)) = 0 then 
    max(tlq_inst) keep (dense_rank first order by utctime)
  else
    'Q'
  end as result
from a_5min_tst1
where utctime >= to_date ('01/08/2013 01:00:01','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
and utctime < to_date ('01/08/2013 02:00:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
and pointnumber = 330062;
```

Comment: Excellent sr. Just I added parenthesis like this: " max(tlq_inst) keep (dense_rank first order by utctime) "    Thankyou very much!

Comment: Oh sorry, yes, I missed the parantheses. I'll add them to my answer so as not to confuse other readers.